# algorithm for finding a straight line to separate class

Tags: algorithms

I want create algorithm, which find a straight line which will separate the most objects from the class. The line must be parallel to the X or Y axis. Example:

[image]

Above example present two class: circles filled and unfilled. Red line is a solution to the problem. Has anyone the idea how to find such a simple?

Comment: What does 'separate the most objects' mean? In particular, do all 'separated' points that are separated need to be of the chosen class, or do we allow points of another class at the cost of some score penalty? Additionally, you seem to be suggesting that all points have 2 coordinates. If so, please make that explicit in your question.

Answer (score 1):

First sort data base on their $y$ value. Then find the minimum and maximum value between members of the second class which is denoted by $y_{min_2}$ and $y_{max_2}$, respectively. Then, line with equation of $y = y_{min_2}$ and $y = y_{max_2}$ are candidate. We can count the number of first class member in sides of these two lines in $O(\log(n))$.

Therefore, we find an algorithm which works in $O(n\log(n))$.